# How to set super class properties in @Immutable classes?

Tags: inheritance, groovy, immutability

Given

```
import groovy.transform.Immutable

class A {
  String a
}

@Immutable
class B extends A {
  String b
}
```

When I try to set the values using the map constructor

```
def b = new B(a: "a", b: "b")
```

then `a` ist still null:

```
groovy:000> b = new B(a: "a", b: "b")
===> B(b)
groovy:000> b.b
===> b
groovy:000> b.a
===> null
```

Is it possible to define an `@Immutable` class which considers the properties of its super classes in the map constructor?

I am using Groovy 2.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code for the [ImmutableASTTransformation](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/transform/ImmutableASTTransformation.java), the Map-arg constructor added by the `createConstructorMapCommon` method does not include a call to `super(args)` in the method body.

I'm not sure if this omission is intentional or accidental; regardless, this class would need to be modified in order to achieve what you're looking for. In the meantime, my only suggestion is to use composition instead of inheritance with `@Delegate` to simplify access to `A`'s properties.

```
import groovy.transform.*

@TupleConstructor
class A {
  String a
}

@Immutable(knownImmutableClasses=[A])
class B {
  @Delegate A base
  String b
}

def b = new B(base: new A("a"), b: "b")
println b.a
```

However, since `A` is mutable (even though we declare it immutable in the `@Immutable` annotation, `B` becomes mutable, too, e.g.

```
b.a = 'foo' // succeeds
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run across this as well. You can get around it by calling the getter method groovy auto adds for you on the property instead of directly accessing the property (in your example b.getA() instead of b.a )

Here's a stupid example....

```
class base{
    def name;
    def myNameIs(){
         return name;//willl return null when called from extending class person
    }
    def extendersNameIs(){
       return getName()// will return extending class default value
    }
 }
 class person extends base{
     def name="betty"//override set default value
  }
  def m=new person();
  println m.myNameIs(); // outputs null
  println m.extendersNameIs();//outputs "betty"
```

See it in action https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5193965758316544
This isn't always an ideal solution, but it's a workaround.

Comment: The question was about the "map constructor". That one does not turn up in your example. Even if that worked, the different return values (property vs. getter) would seem to be quite problematic.